# SQL Server 2000 Named Instance cannot connect remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, sql-server-2000

To facilitate a migration I installed SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition and Service Pack 4 as a named instance on server with an existing instance of SQL Server 2008R2 RTM.

The issue I have is connecting to the named instance outside of the server itself.

This is what worked:

- Connecting remotely while specifying the port number in the connection string (`SERVER\INSTANCE,PORT`)
- Connecting locally using just `SERVER\INSTANCE`

The SQL Server Browser service is enabled and running for SQL Server 2008R2. In the event log there is a warning from the browser service that states:

> ```
> The configuration of the SQL instance *INSTANCE_NAME* is not valid.
> ```

I have been troubleshooting this issue for awhile and cannot find any solid information.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you tried below two links sorry SQL2000 is very old and I have to cudjel my brains a lot to remember any such issue http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/eliminate-sqlbrowser-warnings-non-existent-instances http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/09/18/sql-browser-service-is-not-running-on-server.aspx   it asks about some reg edit can you try that

Comment: So if `server\instance,port` works remotely, why not use that?

Comment: might be a compound issue.  Can you check if you can connect to the server UDP Port 1434 and can you check if the server is listening to the port via netstat -an?  Then check to make sure the firewall has that port enabled.  Check service to ensure it's actually still on.  If it is, check out this link from back in the day: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/eliminate-sqlbrowser-warnings-non-existent-instances.  ALSO CHECK REVERSE DNS and also try to connect to the server via \\IP\instance.